# Skipped lines on mysql load local data

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

There is an example of my csv file:

```
direction,latitude,longitude,metrictimestamp,odometer,routecode,speed,device_deviceid,vehicle_vehicleid
180,-3.724404,-38.557694,20180201025934,161245809,0,0,148469,33089
0,-3.878595,-38.533493,20180201025955,19030291,0,0,8155064,34489
135,-3.744851,-38.545571,20180201025959,55697826,0,3,134680,32040
```

And there is the execution of the import query:

[image]

**Any ideas of why this lines are being skipped??**

Comment: Line terminated by '\r\n' - it's worth stating your os and mysql versions and please add your load statement and table definition as text which we can use rather the useless images.Also you are not loading id so you should tell load data which columns you are loading.

Comment: Create a file with those 3 lines + the headers and run `load data local infile` for that new file. Then, type `show warnings;` and see what MySQL is telling you about those 3 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SHOW WARNINGS` after `LOAD DATA` to show what went wrong. Please note that by default it doesn't show *all* 35 million warnings but just a first few.

That said, your data doesn't include anything for 'id' so that's probably at least part of the issue. Another is that you don't enclose the fields in double quotes but do have `ENCLOSED BY '"'`

See [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) documentation to see how you can choose which fields to populate:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Public/Downloads/Dados.csv'
    INTO TABLE data
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
(direction, latitude, longnitude, metrictimestamp,
    odometer, routecode, speed, deviceid, vehicleid)
```

As `id` is AUTO INCREMENT, it will be populated automatically.

Comment: the error was with the id column, can you tell me how can i put an autoincrement columun id there?

Comment: @ArturBraga, I updated the answer. Usually follow up questions should be asked as a new question.